# AutoHotKey while loop breaks

Tags: autohotkey

```
$*e::
  While GetKeyState("e","P")
  {
    Send, {Blind}e
    Sleep, 10 ; every 10 miliseconds
  }
Return
```

Every few uses the while loop breaks and keeps spamming forever until i press the bind again.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue, could you please provide more details or possibly create a video documenting this issue?

Comment: @Spyre I'm able to replicate it only if I use SendMode Input, which, to be fair, is in the standard AHK header.  I assume the OP has left the standard AHK header in their script.

Comment: @Spyre https://vimeo.com/526661580 link to the video i just recorded (i just do few press and it works fine and than it breaks and starts spamming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am still unable to replicate this issue, based on what @Charlie Armstrong mentioned, the script may work properly if `SendEvent` is used instead of a `SendInput`. The following modified script would still keep the `SendMode` as `Input`, but would override only the `Send` statement inside the while loop.

```
$*e::
  While GetKeyState("e","P")
  {
    SendEvent, {Blind}e
    Sleep, 10 ; every 10 miliseconds
  }
Return
```

More information about `Send` and `SendMode` can be found [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) and [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm).